# Using the Javascript Fetch API with Hapi

Tags: post, hapi.js, payload, fetch-api

I created a simple API with Hapi that has a route I can POST to, which looks like this:

```
server.route({
  method: "POST",
  path: "/hello",
  handler: function(request, reply) {
    // It doesn't ever get to here
    return reply({hello: request.payload.name});
  },
  config: {
    validate: {
      payload: {
        name: Joi.string().required()
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I can successfully send a POST request to this path in Postman:
[image: Postman Request]
It returns the expected response. But, when I use this piece of Javascript to send the request:

```
fetch("http://localhost:1111/hello", {
  mode: "cors"
  body: {name: "John Doe"}
}).then(() => {
  console.log("yay! it worked");
});
```

This fails, and says "value" must be an object.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, I just needed to stringify the JSON first, and then it worked:

```
fetch("http://localhost:1111/hello", {
  mode: "cors"
  body: JSON.stringify({name: "John Doe"})
}).then(() => {
  console.log("yay! it worked");
});
```